# Can I use TextBlock TextTrimming to trim only the first Run, not the whole thing?

Tags: wpf, textblock, word-wrap

I have a TextBlock like this:

```
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxHeight="50">
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
      <Run Text="Some text that might be long so I want it wordwrapped." />
      <Run Text="Link" />
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
  </TextBlock>
```

The second Run is formatted like a hyperlink.  Unfortunately, when the first run is long enough to force an ellipsis, the Link gets cut off.  What I would like to happen is this:

```
Some text that might
be long so I...  Link
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

With The TextTrimming set to CharacterEllipsis I'm assuming you want it to cut off a line that is too long.

Ex)

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
  <Run Text="Some text that might be long so I want it wordwrapped." />
  <Run Text="Link" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

Should show
"Some text that might be long..."
"Link"

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxHeight="50">
   <TextBlock.Inlines>
      <Run Text="Some text that might be long so I want it wordwrapped." />
      <Run Text="Link" />
   </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

If this is what you want to achieve then just remove the TextWrapping="Wrap"

Here are a couple of things to take a look at:

Does it have to be **one TextBlock**?
If not you can do the following...

```
<WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Some text that might be long so I want it wordwrapped. " TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
       <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Link</Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</WrapPanel>
```

Does it have to be a **TextBlock**?
If not you can do the following...

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        Some text that might be long so I want it wordwrapped.
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Link</Hyperlink> .
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Are these solutions of any help?

Comment: This isn't want to I want to achieve.  I want the Link to go after the text, not below it.  And I want the text to be wrapped, since I have limited horizontal space to work with.

Comment: Sorry, none of those seem to do what I want.  What I want is for the text to be wrapped and trimmed if necessary, but for the Link to appear on the last line directly after the ellipsis.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but I'm pretty sure you *can't* do this without creating your own custom TextBlock that inherits from TextBlock (and some trickery)

Comment: I see... That's unfortunate. Make an answer to that effect, and I'll accept it.